# Howto find my xorg.conf. Where is it?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

I can't find my xorg.conf.

There is no xorg.conf file by default in Ubuntu 11.04.

If I run: "whereis xorg.conf" I am seeing: xorg: /usr/lib/xorg /usr/lib64/xorg /usr/include/xorg

may be I just can create it by myself? at /etc/X11/xorg.conf?

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate, no?  Here's one version on a different SE: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config

> To create an initial /etc/xorg.conf file, you can have Xorg's autoconfiguration output a full blown static one for you:
>
> ```
> sudo Xorg -configure
> ```
>
> or create an /etc/xorg.conf containing only those sections and options that you need to override Xorg's autoconfigurated settings.

Comment: in order to do that XServer needs to be down. I can't afford this. Is there any way to get xorg.conf without shutting xorg off?

Comment: "sudo Xorg :2 -configure" did work.

Answer (score 7):

The modern implementations of Xorg doesn't need a xorg.conf file, the configuration is automatic. And the correct place for the xorg.conf file is /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

Comment: Juan, corrected.