# change colour depth

Tags: debian, xorg, configuration, xfce, powerpc

How do I change the colour depth? It says online to edit the `xorg.conf` file, but I don't have that. I am running Debian XFCE on a Powerbook G4

Answer (score 5):

[Create an `xorg.conf` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18991/howto-find-my-xorg-conf-where-is-it) by running `Xorg -configure`. Then edit the `Depth` entry in the `Display` subsection of the `Screen` section.

You can start an X server with a non-default depth by running e.g. `startx -- -depth 8`.

If you already have a running X server, pick a different display number (if the display you choose is already in use, you'll get the message “Server is already active for display *NUMBER*”). The default display number is 0. To indicate the display number, pass a `:NUMBER` argument to the X server. For example:

```
Xorg :1 -configure
startx -- :1 -depth 8
```

Comment: I cannot do this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28119/not-able-to-create-xorg-conf-file

Comment: Me neither: `$ sudo Xorg -configure  

Server is already active for display 0
`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant See my answer to gadgetmo's question.