# not able to create xorg.conf file

Tags: debian, xorg, configuration, xfce, powerpc

I want to change my colour depth. I posted [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28073/change-colour-depth), and got [the following answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28073/change-colour-depth/28101):

> [Create an `xorg.conf` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18991/howto-find-my-xorg-conf-where-is-it) by running `Xorg -configure`. Then edit the `Depth` entry in the `Display` subsection of the `Screen` section.
>
> You can start an X server with a non-default depth by running e.g. `startx -- -depth 8`.

So I run `sudo Xorg -configure`, but I get this error:

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
        If this server is no longer running, remove /temp/.X0-lock
        and start again.
```

So I run `sudo rm -rf /temp/.X0-lock`.

And then I run `sudo Xorg -configure`, but get this:

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running

Fatal server error:
Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running
```

What do I do? I have a PowerBook G4 running XFCE Debian.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> doesn't (seem to) do anything. (?)

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure you run Xorg -configure when not running X, as the errors hints against. Try killing X with `Ctrl+Alt+Bksp` and switch to a tty with `Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6]`and login - or if you use the GDM display manager (your login program), login to a tty and issue `/etc/init.d/gdm stop` from there to kill X. If the command completes successfully it should generate a default /etc/X11/xorg.conf which you should edit. After editing you start X with `startx` and do the testing needed.

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+Bksp` doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you use GDM as a display manager (your login program), try `/etc/init.d/gdm stop` from a tty to kill X.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, if you already have an X server running, you need to specify a different display number (a display number uniquely identifies the X server, so each X server must have its own display number). Try

```
Xorg :1 -configure
```

(executed as root, i.e. `sudo Xorg :1 -configure` or `su -c 'Xorg :1 -configure'` if you're starting from your own account).