# Changing color depth in linux mint

Tags: x11, linux-mint, display-settings, color-management

How can I alter color depth settings in Linux Mint 13 maya?
I tried to find the `xorg.conf` in

```
/etc/X11/
```

But I could not find the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [change colour depth](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28073/change-colour-depth)

Comment: And perhaps see also [Howto find my xorg.conf. Where is it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18991) and [not able to create xorg.conf file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28119)